# Regex match and take N symbols when they are mixed with symbols which you don't have to take

Tags: regex

Here's a couple of examples:

NUM12345678OTHERSTR

NUM 123 45 678 OTHERSTR

NUM123 45-678 OTHERSTR

NUM 123 456 789 1011

I need to get 12345678

So I need to select number which is located after the certain marker NUM and may include digits mixed with spaces and dashes. That's not a problem, I'm able to create a pattern like this. But I need to limit this number either with another marker(OTHERSTR) OR with its length.  I need to select e.g. at least 4 and up to 8 digits max. I thought about {4,8}, but couldn't figure out how to apply it only to digits but not to spaces etc. Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Asking Robin's question again? in what programming language? additionally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: First remove all spaces and dashes from the string, then proceed matching as you would have.

Answer (score 0):

for delimiting with string

```
(?<=NUM).*(?=OTHERSTR)
```

for delimiting with number of chars :

```
^\D*((?:\d\D*){4,8})
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/aL6tE7

you will get `123 456 78` in the first capture group, for which you can do a regex substitution of spaces with nothing to get your desired output. So on the result that you are getting, do regex substitution of `\D+` with nothing.